# Mocking mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose model in a helper file, how can i stub the model and utilize find,update functionality

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
User = mongoose.model('User')
User.findById(userId).exec().then(function (boardExist) {});
```

So how can i mock/stub find,update functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i stubbed the functionality

`sinon.stub(User, 'findById')
.returns(Promise.resolve('ReturnExpectedObject')
 );`